# .net thread safe many clicks at button

Tags: c#, .net

I have event

```
button.Click += ProcessClick;
```

and my event handler `ProcessClick` is:

```
private void async ProcessClick(object o, EventArgs e){
    await LongOperation()
}
```

When I will click button quickly many times, 
**How** to process only the first thread and skip other threads, until the first is done?

Disabling button after first click is not a solution...

**EDIT**: utilizing any type of thread constructions is acceptable: Tasks, Semaphores, locks and so on.

Comment: "Disabling button after first click is not a solution..." -- Why not? It is the simplest and most straightforward solution.

Comment: It is related to our cross-platform mobile framework. It should be better *Touch* event instead of *Click* in my *question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the event after the first click and add it again at the end of processing the first click.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Write("Running click event");
    this.button1.Click -= button1_Click;

    await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(5000));

    this.button1.Click += button1_Click;
}
```

Comment: +1, nice one. You could even switch the handler to something more appropriate, e.g. `this.button1.Click += showOperationAlreadyRunningMessage;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool longOperationRunning;

private void async ProcessClick(object o, EventArgs e){
    if (longOperationRunning)
        return;

    longOperationRunning = true;
    await LongOperation()
    longOperationRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: You are right. But since "is the operation already running" is a global type of state (at least global to your current form instance), I don't see a way to avoid it.